# Transform TransferOrder into ItemFulfillment with error SSS_INVALID_SUBLIST_OPERATION

Tags: transform, netsuite, suitescript, restlet, fulfillment

I have a suite script (RESTlet): transform **Transfer Order** into **Item Fulfillment** on NetSuite

```
/**
 * This SuiteScript RESTlet transforms a Transfer Order into an Item Fulfillment.
 *
 * u/NApiVersion 2.x
 * u/NScriptType Restlet
 * u/NModuleScope SameAccount
 */
define(['N/record'], function(record) {
  function createItemFulfillment(data) {
      var transferOrderId = data.transferOrderId;
      var locationId = data.locationId; // Location ID for the Item Fulfillment
      var lineItems = data.lineItems;
      log.debug('data', data)
      // Load the Transfer Order
    var transferOrder = record.load({
        type: record.Type.TRANSFER_ORDER,
        id: transferOrderId,
        isDynamic: true
      });
    var trandate = transferOrder.getValue('trandate');
    var memo = transferOrder.getValue('memo');
    
    log.debug('trandate', trandate)
    log.debug('memo', memo)
      // Create an Item Fulfillment
      var itemFulfillment = record.transform({
        fromType: 'transferorder',
        fromId: transferOrderId,
        toType: 'itemfulfillment',
        isDynamic: true
      });

    var fulfill = itemFulfillment.
    log.debug('itemFulfillment', itemFulfillment)
      // Set the location on the Item Fulfillment
   //   itemFulfillment.setValue('location', locationId); 
      itemFulfillment.setValue({ fieldId: 'trandate', value: trandate }); //new Date()

      // Loop through Transfer Order lines and copy them to Item Fulfillment
     var lineItemCount = transferOrder.getLineCount({ sublistId: 'item' });

      // Loop through Transfer Order line items and copy them to Item Fulfillment
      for (var i = 0; i < lineItemCount; i++) {
        try {
        var itemId = transferOrder.getSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', fieldId: 'item', line: i });
        var quantity = transferOrder.getSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', fieldId: 'quantity', line: i });

        log.debug('item', itemId)
        log.debug('quantity', quantity)
        
        itemFulfillment.selectNewLine({ sublistId: 'item' });
        itemFulfillment.setCurrentSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', fieldId: 'item', value: itemId });
        itemFulfillment.setCurrentSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', fieldId: 'quantity', value: quantity });
        // You can set more sublist fields if needed
        itemFulfillment.commitLine({ sublistId: 'item' });
      } catch (ex){
          log.error('Sublist Operation Error', ex.message);
    return { success: false, errorMessage: ex.message };
  }
      }
      // Save the Item Fulfillment
      var fulfillmentId = itemFulfillment.save();
      return fulfillmentId;
  }

  function doPost(context) {
  if (context) { // Check if there is a request object
    var requestData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(context)); // Parse the request body
    var response = createItemFulfillment(requestData);
    return response;
  } else {
    return { error: 'abcxyz' };
  }
}

  return {
    post: doPost
  };
});
```

on **Postman**, at requestBody I set a value **transferOrderID**.

Then, I receive an error:

**SSS_INVALID_SUBLIST_OPERATION**: You have attempted an invalid sublist or line item operation. You are either trying to access a field on a non-existent line or you are trying to add or remove lines from a static sublist.

I tried log.debug and get the value of Transfer Order is okay, but I could not set the value for Item Fulfillment .

**Can someone help me? I really appreciate your support efforts.**

I tried log.debug and get the value of Transfer Order is okay, but I could not set the value for Item Fulfillment .

Comment: Two additional options to help debug besides adding more logging: 1. Do the same thing in the UI and see if there are errors. 2. Use the SuiteScript Debugger to step through your code and see what line throws the error and with what values.

Answer (score 1):

When you create (transform) an item fulfillment from a transfer order, it is created with all the lines corresponding to fulfillable lines on the order.  You cannot *add* lines, as you are attempting to do with `itemFulfillment.selectNewLine({ sublistId: 'item' });`.

You can observe this if you fulfill an order in the UI - there is no option to add lines, as there is on an order, for example.  You can also use `itemFulfillment.getLineCount('item')` immediately after `record.transform()` to verify that the lines already exist.

Use `itemFulfillment.selectLine()` (instead of `selectNewLine()`) if you need to make changes to the values in the item lines.  Be aware that you can only set the same values you would be able to in the UI - for example if your settings restrict fulfillment based on item commitment, you won't be able to set a quantity to fulfill that's greater than the *committed* quantity - a scenario that may arise with the code in your example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I have solved it.

Now, I tried transform Transfer Order into Item Receipt on NetSuite using suitescript (RESTlet).

I transformed and an Item Receipt have created, but it so slowly (took about 4 minutes). I want to optimization it. Can you help me ?

Comment: You're welcome.  For the Item Receipt issue, I'd suggest adding a new question with your script and any other relevant information.  ATB.